# Multitouch GTK3 Example

Tags: multi-touch, gtk3

From what I understand, multitouch support was added to GTK+ as of version 3.4. What I'm not clear on is whether this applies just to touch screens like phones/tablets or whether it extends to Apple style touch pads (the way Ubuntu/Unity and OS X use multitouch gestures on the touchpad).

I've also had a hard time finding examples of how to implement gestures and how to track multitouch events.

Are there any good examples of how to implement multitouch with GTK (or something related like Clutter)?

Answer (score 1):

I also couldn't find examples so here is my knowledge about it:

### Mouse events (introduction):

When using mouse Gdk propagates events `GDK_BUTTON_PRESS`, `GDK_BUTTON_RELEASE` (and a few [other](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/3.24/gdk3-Events.html#GdkEventType)). That gets translated into `GtkWidget` signals like [button-press-event](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.24/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-press-event) and then into higher level ones like `GtkButton`'s [clicked](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.24/GtkButton.html#GtkButton-clicked) if applicable. Connecting a callback to the `button-press-event` signal allows access to [GdkEventButton structure](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/3.24/gdk3-Event-Structures.html#GdkEventButton). Using `clicked` however frees you from keeping track whether it was a click (press & release) or only a release (during kinetic scrolling for instance).

### Touch events:

Touch works a little bit different. There are [4 touch events](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/3.24/gdk3-Events.html#GDK-TOUCH-BEGIN:CAPS):

> GDK_TOUCH_BEGIN
>   A new touch event sequence has just started. This event type was added
>   in 3.4.
>
> GDK_TOUCH_UPDATE
>   A touch event sequence has been updated. This event type was added in
>   3.4.
>
> GDK_TOUCH_END
>   A touch event sequence has finished. This event type was added in 3.4.
>
> GDK_TOUCH_CANCEL
>   A touch event sequence has been canceled. This event type was added in
>   3.4.

and [GdkEventTouch structure](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/3.24/gdk3-Event-Structures.html#GdkEventTouch) uses [GdkEventSequence](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/3.24/gdk3-Events.html#GdkEventSequence) for differentiating between fingers. It seems to me that it is simply a value (couldn't find definition in the sources) but I may be mistaken here. `GtkWidget` has [touch-event](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.24/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-touch-event) signal similar to `button-press-event` etc that also gets translated into events like `clicked`.

### Sample code (using gtkmm but core aspects are the same):

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create();
    Gtk::Window window;
    window.set_default_size(1024, 768);
    app->signal_startup().connect([&]
    {
        app->add_window(window);
    });

    window.show();

    //code works for me without adding events mask but let's be thorough
    window.add_events(Gdk::TOUCH_MASK);
    window.signal_touch_event().connect([&](GdkEventTouch* event)->bool
    {
        std::cout<<"TOUCH EVENT: ";
        switch(event->type)
        {
        case GDK_TOUCH_BEGIN:
            std::cout<<"begin ";
            break;
        case GDK_TOUCH_UPDATE:
            std::cout<<"update ";
            break;
        case GDK_TOUCH_END:
            std::cout<<"end ";
            break;
        case GDK_TOUCH_CANCEL:
            std::cout<<"cancel ";
            break;
        default:
            std::cout<<"something else ";
        }
        std::cout<<event->sequence<<" "
                 <<gdk_event_get_event_sequence((GdkEvent*)event)<<" "
                 <<std::endl;
        return GDK_EVENT_PROPAGATE;
    });
    window.signal_event().connect([&](GdkEvent* event)->bool
    {
        std::cout<<"EVENT: "<<event->type<<std::endl;
        return GDK_EVENT_PROPAGATE;
    });

    app->run();
    return 0;
}
```

### Touchpad events:

There are also [touchpad & pad events](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/3.24/gdk3-Events.html#GDK-TOUCHPAD-SWIPE:CAPS) and [structures](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/3.24/gdk3-Event-Structures.html#GdkEventTouchpadSwipe) but it seems that there is no explicit handling of these on `Gtk` level. It has to be done in callback for [event](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.24/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-event) signal with checking [GdkEventType](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/3.24/gdk3-Event-Structures.html#GdkEvent) and casting it into appropriate structures.